# How can I make maven fail on Windows if it is not running as Administrator

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that builds an installer, as part of this process it needs to be running in an Administrator cmd shell.
The bad thing is that it will run for about 15 minutes and HAPPILY produce the wrong output if it is NOT running as Admin.
I would like to make maven exit with an error if it is not running as Admin.
What is an easy way to do this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use .bat files?

Comment: What's the overall process, it doesn't sound something a build should actually do, you need to build a project using Maven afterall, not having advanced behaviors for similar stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem by executing a batch at the start of the build, and fail the build if the batch does not detect admin mode (and thus returns a specific failure code).

To be more precise:

- Executing the batch can be done with the `maven-exec-plugin`. You
  have to bind it to the `validate` phase in order to execute it right
  at the start of the build (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).
- The content of the batch is up to you. What does it mean to be admin
  ? You can try to create a file in c:\ for example and return an error
  code if it fails.
- Finally you can use the `successCodes` of the `maven-exec-plugin` to make the build fail if you are not admin. This
  parameter is documented here:
  http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes